# JavaFX Thread.Sleep() or pause() in ActionEvent

Tags: java, javafx, wait, sleep, pause

I'm new at JavaFX and I was trying whenever I press the button, ***first***, it shows some info on a label, ***then*** change the scene.
Everything is OK actually, but I just couldn't find how to wait for a specific amount of time before the change scene.

I tried with Thread.sleep() like this: (its wait properly, but somehow it doesn't change the text of the label)

```
    @FXML
public void pressButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    user = new User(inUsername.getText(),inPassword.getText());
    lLeftBottom.setText(user.getUserInfo());
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    changeScene2(event);
}
```

(edit, thanks to [Slaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6395627/slaw) for solution about the pause()'s actionEvent problem)

and also I try about JavaFX's pause method, but it doesn't wait, still jumping the other scene immediately

```
    @FXML
public void pressButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    user = new User(inUsername.getText(),inPassword.getText());
    PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(3));
    pause.setOnFinished(e ->{
        lLeftBottom.setText(user.getUserInfo());
    });
    pause.play();
    changeScene2(event);
}
```

How can I make this delay ?

Comment: Yes, thank you this solve the error. but it doesn't wait when I press the button, it's still jumping the other scene immediately

Comment: The code in the `onFinished` handler is executed after the pause (when the pause finishes) so you have this backwards.

Comment: Thank you very much, I get it how pause works now, that solves my problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used the PauseTransition backwards.  If you want to change the scene after the pause, that is the part that needs to be in your onFinished event handler:

```
@FXML
public void pressButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    user = new User(inUsername.getText(),inPassword.getText());
    PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(3));
    pause.setOnFinished(e ->{
        changeScene2(event);
    });
    lLeftBottom.setText(user.getUserInfo());
    pause.play();
}
```

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thank you very much that solve my problem!

Answer (score -3):

About your first question: Try using try catch. Worked out for me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("test1");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("test2");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's waiting yes, but somehow its doesn't set the text of label. While I using the throw exception on sleep(), its wait properly but doesn't change the label's text too.

Comment: You should never call `Thread#sleep(...)` on the _JavaFX Application Thread_. That thread must be responsive at all times (@EgeBULUT )

Comment: @Slaw oh, I get it thanks. I'll use `PauseTransition` from now on